# Jquery parece não atualizar

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Tenho um código de Customer = 3368. Fiz uma função **jquery** que pega o código do **Dropdown**, que pode ser 1 ou 3368(só tem dois registros lá na dropdown). Acontece que quando eu tenho na dropdown 1 o customer é 3368 e se troco o dropdown para 3368 aí o customer vai pra 1. Essa é a jquery que comecei a montar

```
$('#btnSalvar').click(function () {
        var dropdown = $('#faturarPara').val();
        var customerId = @Model.CustomerId;
        alert('Drop2 é: ' + dropdown + ' e customer é: ' + customerId);
    });
```

O que me intriga em tudo isso é se eu rodo uma outra jquery na chamada do change da dropdown, aí funciona 1 e 3368 e depois 3368 e 3368. Mas depois não rola mais. Essa é a do change

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#faturarPara').change(function () {
            var idFaturarDrop = $(this).val();
            var customerId = @Model.CustomerId;

            alert('Customer é: ' + customerId + ' customer options = ' + idFaturarDrop);
        });
    });
```

Sinceramente não entendo. O correto seria: Na dropdown eu mudo (de->para)
**Revenda->Cliente Final**(3368 e 3368). De **Cliente Final->Revenda**(3368 e 1)

Essa é a Dropdown

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CustomerId, new SelectList(Model.Options, "CustomerId", "Description", Model.CustomerId), new { @id= "faturarPara" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Ola, entao eu penso que o problema aqui deve ser o event OnChange que e acionado quando carregas o teu dropdown pois ele considera a mudança de vazio para algo e recupera esse valor, se tens um dropdown pensa em utilizar o [.select()](https://api.jquery.com/select/) isso e se o value for o valor que queres recuperar, senao podes tambem usar

`$( "#iddoteuselect option:selected" ).text()`

para recuperar o texto das tuas opcoes

EDIT

```
 var customerId = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('CustomerId')
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas o que preciso é comparar os dois ID's, o que pego na DropDown(variável) com o ID da model(fixo). Não sei se pegar o text seria o correto. Preciso do ID dele

Comment: Preciso de um pouco mais de contexto pra poder ajudar nao vou mentir, mas o indice de um dropdown comeca em zero. 

Mas eu penso que recuperar o valor do item selecionado seria suficiente 

'var id = $('.selected-item').val();'

E depois podes se comparar o id recuperado

Comment: Postei o código da Dropdown. O que eu quero é comparar os ID's passados.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta

Comment: ScrapBench, estou pegando um undefined nessa abordagem sua.,

Comment: Estranho não deve estar a recuperar o valor do select no entanto se perbeci bem o atributo é CustomerId

Comment: O meu problema não está no ID da dropdown, este está correto. A questão toda está no customerId. Ele está mudando e não deveria, ao meu ver, apenas o ID da drop deveria alterar. O outro é fixo e ainda não conseguir entender o porquê

Comment: atraves de que variavel estas a transferir o customerId que esta a causar problema ?